# Unable to create an ARRAYFORMULA that will AVERAGE the results of a QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a sheet `data` that tracks client transactions.

1. Each row is a transaction
2. The columns are:

   - `LAST NAME`
   - `PHONE NUMBER`
   - `SUB`
   - `TOTAL`
   - `TIP`
   - `PERCENTAGE`
3. The `TIP` and `PERCENTAGE` columns are calculated based on the information  entered in the `SUB` and `TOTAL` columns.

I am trying to write a formula in another sheet `average` that returns the average tip percentage for each client based on their transactions.  Clients are uniquely identified based on their `LAST NAME` and `PHONE NUMBER` fields.

Here's a sample of the `data` sheet before transformation:

| LAST NAME | PHONE NUMBER | SUB | TOTAL | TIP | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | (123) 456-7890 | $28.66 | $32.96 | $4.30 | 13.05% |
| Johnson | (987) 654-3210 | $58.68 | $68.68 | $10.00 | 14.56% |
| Williams | (555) 123-4567 | $35.48 | $40.48 | $5.00 | 12.35% |
| Jones | (111) 222-3334 | $52.22 | $55.00 | $2.78 | 5.05% |
| Smith | (123) 456-7890 | $50.82 | $70.82 | $20.00 | 28.24% |
| Johnson | (987) 654-3210 | $51.23 | $58.68 | $7.45 | 12.70% |
| Williams | (555) 123-4567 | $33.47 | $35.47 | $2.00 | 5.64% |
| Jones | (111) 222-3334 | $44.27 | $50.91 | $6.64 | 13.04% |

Example result in the `average` sheet using the sample above:

| LAST NAME | PHONE NUMBER | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | (123) 456-7890 | 20.64% |
| Johnson | (987) 654-3210 | 13.63% |
| Williams | (555) 123-4567 | 9.00% |
| Jones | (111) 222-3334 | 9.05% |

The following formula didn't work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(A2<>"", AVERAGE(QUERY(Data!A2:F, 
     "SELECT F WHERE (A='"&A2&"' AND B CONTAINS '"&B2&"')")),
     IFERROR(1/0)))
```

I'm considering using VLOOKUP but need help with the implementation.

I would to use an array formula placed in the top cell of the `average` sheet that will spill down and update automatically whenever  transactions are added.

To provide more context and facilitate the process, I have prepared an editable Google sheet containing all generated data. You can access it through the following link: [Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BjDTyCdWbqEPw8dMu8uAJ4cbd1oMtjS7oPCMvqy8Q64/edit?usp=sharing).

Can someone assist in rewriting the formula or suggest an alternative approach to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:D, 
   "Select A, B, 1-SUM(C)/SUM(D) Where A is not NULL
    group by A, B label 1-SUM(C)/SUM(D) ''")
```

[image]

#### Alternate Formula

Same as above but adds the $ columns as well.

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:E, 
  "Select A, B, SUM(C), SUM(E), SUM(D), 1-SUM(C)/SUM(D)
   where A is not NULL group by A, B label SUM(C) '', 
   SUM(E) '', SUM(D) '', 1-SUM(C)/SUM(D) ''")
```

[image]